# Where to translate SHOW DETAILS from a display view?

Tags: views

I would like to find out where would I be able to translate the SHOW DETAILS/HIDE DETAILS menu options a DATATABLES FORMAT view.
We are using Drupal 7, and I have tried to find it in the Configuration options, with no success. Would this need to be changed in the back end of Drupal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This string seems to be a part of the interface, so you can translate it through `Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface` (`/admin/config/regional/translate/translate`).

You have to enter the exact capitalisation into the search as is written in code (it's case sensitive), not necessarily what you see on the screen (CSS can affect what capitalisation is used in display).

The string won't appear on this list unless you have visited a page with that string in another language (other than English) so Drupal picks it up and makes it available for translation.

Comment: The Show / Hide Details is part of a view, and our sites are in English and French. When I go on the French site, and access that page with the view, the SHOW DETAILS isn't translated, and when I go to where you mention, Translate Interface, the Show Details string isn't in the list. Would it be listed somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have Views translation module enabled? Is there something within DataTables module incompatible with using translations? Is the string "Show details" coming from that module? If it's been properly implemented, even in javascript, the string will register through the Translate interface. Did you take a look here: [Multilingual Datatables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables/issues/1556054) or updated to the dev version?